# Python - How to create a script which can simulate user actions on a website

Tags: python, selenium, web

Brief:
I want to create a program in Python which can programmatically login to a website and performs functions:
- Click anchor links
- Click buttons
- Type into text fields
- Submit forms

I'm using Python 3.6.2

I've searched for a while now and seem to see selenium as a recommended option, however once I install it and use it I can't seem to work around the errors I get: geckodriver not in PATH even though I specifically set it in the path. That was all on Python 2.7. Could I have an approach which explains where to correctly install selenium or whatever module is needed and some examples of the requirements in the list above.

If you have any questions please ask them I'm here waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that gecko driver is not in the path, depends on which system you are:

in ubuntu it should be in /bin
in mac it should be in user/local/bin
in windows it should be specified in the path string

one common solution is to place it in the same directory where you script is
and using webdriver.Firefox('./firefoxdriver')
or however, you called it.

Comment: Let me try that